# Create two variables from parsed string

Tags: parsing, coldfusion, split

I'm trying to parse a string into two variables. The source is a SQL query that populates values for multiple checkboxes. The number of checkboxes varies base on the query results. The checkboxes are coded:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Listname" value="#RecID#:#DistListName#" ID="ListName#ListID#">
```

Using code I found here, I remove the `:` separating RecID and DistListName with:

```
<cfset PreParseList = #form.Listname#>    
<cfset ParseList = ListToArray(PreParseList, ":", false, true)>
```

The output of ParseList looks like this:

```
627 Corporate IT Desktop Team DL,629 Corporate IT Helpdesk Team DL,607 HMC Behavioral Health DL,257 Kauai Region HR
```

I need to create two variables, one for the RECID which can be 1 to 3 digits long, and one for the name. The RecID gets written to a junction table that controls what distribution lists a user would have access to. The name is just displayed on the confirmation page.

Is what I'm trying even possible, or should I look into a different way of passing the RecID and name?

Comment: Loop through the variable as a list and use ListFirst and listRest

Comment: Your best solution is to normalize your table structure and not store lists though

Answer (score 3):

```
<cfset recIds = []>
<cfset distListNames = []>
<cfloop list="#form.Listname#" index="checkboxValue">
  <cfset arrayAppend(recIds, listFirst(checkboxValue, ':'))>
  <cfset arrayAppend(distListNames, ListRest(checkboxValue, ':'))>
</cfloop>
```

> should I look into a different way of passing the RecID and name?

It'd be logical to only set the value of checkbox to RecID, since "the name is just displayed on the confirmation page".  Then you get a list of `RecIDs` from the `form` scope, ready to be used, for free.  Is the confirmation page a CFM page?  If so, couldn't you display the name(s) that by fetching from DB again by ID(s)?

Comment: Thanks Henry, I was just about to post because I got the loop figured out, but was having trouble with setting the variable, I haven't worked with arrays much, your suggestion worked great. And yes I had thought about just passing the RecID and using that in a SQL query to list the names, could have done that easily, is that the way you would do it? Just thought maybe that was an unnecessary SQL call since I already had the data. But if that's not an issue, I have no problems doing that.  Matt, I'm running out of room, I'll respond to your comment after I post this.

Comment: Matt, as far as the SQL normalization goes, let me know if I'm doing this wrong. I have one table that contains my users, I have another table that contains my distribution lists, then I have a third table, I call it a junction table, it has the user id from the user table, and record id from the distribution list table, that controls what lists that particular user can edit. Granted I end up with the same user id's and distribution list id's appearing numerous times in that table, but I thought that's how you did many to many relationships. Can you suggest a better way? Thanks.

Comment: (Edit)  *RE: Just thought maybe that was an unnecessary SQL call*  No, it is perfectly fine to run another query. Storing both values just adds unnecessary complexity IMO. As Henry mentioned above, typically you store the ID (only) as the checkbox value. That technique has [a number of advantages](http://cfsearching.blogspot.com/2009/07/sot-why-do-people-forget-about-insert.html) over your current method.

Comment: What use does the array serve?  Isn't it just another variable?

Comment: Probably because `Array[i]` is easier to read and write than `ListFirst(ListGetAt(list,i),":")` and likewise with `ListRest()`.

Comment: Once again, thanks to all, great suggestions. To simplify things, I'm going to go ahead and make a second SQL call to get the list name from the RecID for the confirmation page. I like simple!! Now I need to figure out how to display the results in three columns rather than one long column. As bad as I am at this, I'm even worse with html. Thanks again.