# Array contents as a variable

Tags: arrays, coldfusion

Noob question here, I've got all this data in an array, but I can't figure out how to do anything with it. I need to use one element in a SQL update query, the other element is just for display purposes only. This works:

```
<cfset RecID=[]>
<cfset DistListNames=[]>    
<cfloop list="#form.ListName#" index="listcount">    
  <cfset arrayAppend(RecID, listFirst(listcount,":"))>
  <cfset arrayAppend(DistListNames, listLast(listcount, ":"))>    
</cfloop>    
<cfdump var=#RecID#>    
<cfdump var=#DistListNames#>
```

But other than displaying those little green boxes on the action page, I can't do anything with it. How do I set variables from the contents of RecID and DistListNames?

UPDATE:

I ended up going with Dan's suggestion and using the form variable instead of the array, still having trouble getting my head around arrays.

My confirmation page works using this:

```
<cfloop list="#form.ListName#" index="listcount">    
<cfset session.DistListID=(listFirst(listcount,":"))>
<cfset DistListNames=(listLast(listcount, ":"))>    
<cfoutput>    
#session.DistListID# #DistListNames#,&nbsp;    
</cfoutput>    
</cfloop>
```

This gives me the list names on the confirmation page, I just have the RecID's in there now just for testing. So far so good, right?

When I click the "Yes" button to confirm, I run this loop to just output the RecID's to make sure it works before I do basically the same loop around a cfquery for the SQL update. (All this code is on the same page, I don't open another file as the action page.)

```
<cfloop list="#session.DistListID#" index="RecID">    
<cfoutput>#RecID#</cfoutput>    
</cfloop>
```

All I get is the RecID of the last item in the list. I know it's another noob question, but I promise I've been online reading all morning trying to figure this out, I've tried for="1" to="#ListLen(session.DistListID#" but that just gives me a 1. I'm just not getting it.

Thanks

Comment: what do you want to do with the variables?

Comment: Being able to work with arrays (and structs, and objects) is fundamental to being a developer, so you really ought to polish up your skills here. I've documented array usage in CFML in a series of blog articles: http://blog.adamcameron.me/2012/08/arrays-in-coldfusion-part-1.html. Working through those might be beneficial to you in the long term.

Comment: form.listName is a variable with all the data you need.  Your two arrays are unnecessary.

Comment: *All I get is the RecID of the last item in the list* Because you are overwriting the session variable value each time you loop. However, [as mentioned on your other thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29996631/create-two-variables-from-parsed-string), storing both a "name" and "id" within the form field is an over-complication.  You could avoid that loop altogether by storing only the "ID" value. Then the form field would contain a simple list of ID's.  *I do basically the same loop around a cfquery for the SQL update* What exactly does the form update (in plain English, not code)?

Comment: Thanks Leigh, I spent all day today trying to do this in a two dimensional array, was beginning to think you couldn't couldn't scope an array as a session variable. The update writes the user id and the recid of the list to a junction table, that's it. So I think I'm going to go back and just use the recid's and make a second SQL call for the list names on the confirmation page. I'm starting to get a handle on arrays so I'll probably use an array for the recid's just so I can say I did one.

Comment: @toleolu - It is certainly good to understand how to use arrays. However, from what you have described you do not need them and in this case it is actually making things more complicated than necessary. If you look at [the link in my comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29996631/create-two-variables-from-parsed-string#comment48115630_29996784) it demonstrates a much easier way of inserting multiple records via a single INSERT/SELECT.  Assuming the source of "distID" is a table in your database, all you need is the "userID" and a list of "distID's". No arrays. No looping.

Comment: *The update writes the user id and the recid of the list to a junction table, that's it.* Just to clarify, typically junction tables are not "updated". You simply DELETE existing records and INSERT new ones as described in the link above. So again, it sounds like the current code is more complicated than it needs to be for a simple junction table..

Comment: Sorry, my use of terminology is noobish as well. I finally got the confirmation page working using SQL IN, not going to say how long it took me to figure that out :). Now I've got to figure out the insert. Thanks again.

Comment: Got the insert query working this morning, Just wanted to say thanks one last time to everyone for all the help. Great resource, hope I can be of some help to others someday. Mahalo.

Comment: Good to hear. You should post your final query as an answer to help the next guy.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a variable in a SQL statement you would use:

```
<cfquery name="myQuery" datasource="myDatasource">
  UPDATE table_name 
  SET column_name = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#RecID[1]#">
  WHERE...
</cfquery>
```

To just display an array value to the page:

```
<cfoutput>#DistListNames[1]#</cfoutput>
```

To store a value in an array in a CF variable

```
<cfset myVar = DistListNames[1]>
```

Remember that CF arrays use a 1 based index so if you try to use DistListNames[0] you'll get an error.

Comment: you don't need a `cfoutput` around a `cfquery` and always use `cfqueryparam`

Comment: Once again, I can't thank all of you enough for all your help. My first go around with arrays, so all the help is greatly appreciated. Adam, I have been to your blog a number of times, great resource. The part on arrays was confusing at first, but now that I have had a chance to work with them it makes a little more sense. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

OK. After all that, here's what I ended up with:

```
<cfquery name="InsertList" datasource="HHSCIntra">    
<cfloop list=#session.DistListID# index="recids">    
INSERT INTO tbl_DistListJunction (DistListID, userID)    
VALUES (<cfqueryparam value="#recids#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_int">, <cfqueryparam value="#session.listuser#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">)    
</cfloop>    
</cfquery>
```

Suggestions and critique's always welcome.

Thanks again to all.

Comment: While the above will work (after fixing the cfsqltype), as mentioned [there is really no need for looping](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30289902/104223). However, if you must loop, be sure to wrap the above in a [transaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction) to ensure all of the inserts succeed or fails as a single unit.

Comment: Don't I need the loop to write the user id with each list. i.e.  "#recids#" would contain 222,65,455,223,677 but "#session.llistuser#" will only contain 'hhsc\username'.

Comment: No. The SELECT will return one record for *each* ID in the list - ie "222,65,455,223,677" will generate 5 records, without any looping. Did you try [my example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30289902/104223)? If not, do that first. It will make a lot more sense once you see it in action.

Comment: Will do Leigh, and thanks again. Been covered up with some other projects, plus having trouble with a SQL LDAP query I've been trying to get to work for a couple of weeks. Gonna post that, hope you'll keep an eye out for it.

Answer (score 0):

> the update [sic] writes the user id and the recid of the list to a
>   junction table, that's it

Then you do not need loops or arrays.

As mentioned on [your other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29996631/create-two-variables-from-parsed-string), storing both the "id" and "name" within the *same* form field is what is making things more complicated than necessary :) Simply store the "ID" (only) and you can avoid looping altogether.

```
 <!--- changed field "name" to be more descriptive --->
 <input type="checkbox" name="RecIDList" value="#RecID#">
```

When the form is submitted, `FORM.RecIDList` will contain a comma delimited list of "RecID" values. Since the source of those values is a database table, simply feed those ID's into a SELECT statement. Then you can insert all of the selected records in a single query - without looping. Something along these lines (obviously add validation):

```
INSERT INTO tbl_DistListJunction (DistListID, userID)    
SELECT RecID
       , <cfqueryparam value="#session.listUser#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
FROM   YourDistrictTable
WHERE  RecID IN 
       (
        <cfqueryparam value="#FORM.RecIDList#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" list="true">
       )
```

**NB:**

- "cf_sql_int" is not a valid type. The correct type is `cf_sql_integer`

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I changed int to integer, interesting that CF didn't throw an error on that. session.listUser in not a number, it's a string. Thanks again.

Comment: *interesting that CF didn't throw an error on that* It won't complain if you enter a bad value.  You could enter "cf_sql_save_the_bumblebees" and CF would not complain. However, it also will not validate that the input consists of valid integers - so be sure you use the correct type. Side note, why is "listUser" a string rather than a number? What does it represent a single user?